# TypeScript: Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, preact

I reviewed the other questions with a similar title, but cannot apply those solutions to this question. *Please do not mark this question a duplicate without explaining in detail how the other answer applies here.*

Goal is to allow deletion of several PDF files at once by returning an array of objects with each PDF-to-be-deleted as an object in the array.

The list of PDF files is passed in as a string via the `Props` (rowData) and converted to an object in `useEffect`.

```
interface TableRowData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  pdf: string;  // "['bob.pdf', 'sam.pdf', 'art.pdf']"
}
interface ObjPdfsToRemove {
    pdfs2EditType: string;
    catSubcatId: number;
    pdf2del: string;
}
interface DlgEditSubcatPdfsProps {
  rowData: TableRowData;
  onClose(): void;
    pdfs2EditType: string;
}

export const DlgEditSubcatPDFs: FunctionalComponent<DlgEditSubcatPdfsProps> = ({ rowData, pdfs2EditType, onClose }) => {

const [currRowData, setCurrRowData] = useState<TableRowData>(rowData);
const [arrPdfNames, setArrPdfNames] = useState([]);
const [pdfs2Remove, setPdfs2Remove] = useState<ObjPdfsToRemove[] | undefined>(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    setCurrRowData(rowData);
    setArrPdfNames(JSON.parse(rowData.pdf));
}, [rowData]);
```

The PDFs are displayed on screen like this:

```
<div class={style.fileList}>
    {arrPdfNames !== undefined && arrPdfNames?.map((d) => {
        return (
            <div class={style.pdfsFlexRow}>
                <Button className={style.pdfDelBtn} onClick={() => handleDelPdf(d)}>
                    DEL
                </Button>
                <div class={style.pdfFileName}>{d}</div>
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

When the Del button is clicked:

```
const handleDelPdf = (pdf2del: string) => {
    setPdfs2Remove(pdfs2Remove !== undefined => [...pdfs2Remove, {  //ADDED per VLAZ suggestion (pretty sure my syntax incorrect)
        pdfs2EditType: pdfs2EditType,
        catSubcatId: rowData.id,
        pdf2del: pdf2del,
    }]);
};
```

THE ERROR is in `handleDelPdf` (immediately above), on this line:
`setPdfs2Remove(pdfs2Remove => [...pdfs2Remove, {`
                               `^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

When hover the `...pdfs2Remove`, the TS Error reads:

```
Type 'ObjPdfsToRemove[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
-----
(parameter) pdfs2Remove: ObjPdfsToRemove[] | undefined
```

How to fix this error?

#### Updates:

1. Added IF condition `if (pdfs2Remove !== undefined)` to the `handleDelPdf` function, but error remained the same.

Initially added the conditional test like this:

```
    if setPdfs2Remove(pdfs2Remove !== undefined){ //--------------------- ADDED (same error)
        setPdfs2Remove(pdfs2Remove => [...pdfs2Remove, {
            pdfs2EditType: pdfs2EditType,
            catSubcatId: rowData.id,
            pdf2del: pdf2del,
        }]);
    };  //--------------------------------------------------------------- ADDED (same error)
```

2. Removed (1) above and changed the `setPdfs2Remove()` func itself, like this *(this is how the code is now displayed in the original question)*:

```
setPdfs2Remove(pdfs2Remove !== undefined => {
```

but that's not right either.

Comment: TS wants you to handle the case where `pdfs2Remove` is `undefined`.

Comment: Added an IF condition inside the `handleDelPdf` func, but still getting same error. Code updated to show where/how added.

Comment: The `if` is outside where you handle `setPdfs2Remove`. I'm honestly surprised you're not getting a compilation error because you're accessing an undeclared variable.

Comment: "*isn't pdfs2Remove declared by the useState() just above the useEffect*" [No, it's not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNft5.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/WKVdom) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.